# pandas special chars converted to weird chars when saving

Tags: pandas, macos, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have a series of texts:

```
s = ["t1" , "t1", "it wasn’t that simple"]
```

When saving as csv:

```
s.to_csv("s.csv")
```

And then open it in excel, the char `'` changed to the following:

```
"it wasn‚Äôt that simple"
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `encoding='utf-16'`

**Ex:**

```
s = ["t1" , "t1", "it wasn’t that simple"]  
s = pd.Series(s)
s.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-16', index=False)
```